# How to avoid multiple class bindings in SLF4J class path

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, sbt, slf4j

I have a scala code that I have packaged into a jar using `sbt`. I placed that jar under `$SPARK/jars` and on trying to use the classes I get these

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/tmp/hadoop-ubuntu/nm-local-dir/usercache/ubuntu/filecache/87/__spark_libs__5108127367259158326.zip/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
```

After reading suggestions on SO, I added the following to my `build.sbt` to prevent additional binding of `slf4j`

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api"       % "1.7.7",
  "org.slf4j" % "jcl-over-slf4j"  % "1.7.7"
).map(_.force())

libraryDependencies ~= { _.map(_.exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-jdk14")) }
```

This didn't resolve the issue and so I tried another solution I found here and added the following to the `build.sbt` file

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    //depencies
).map(_.exclude("org.slf4j", "*"))

//insert one without exclusion
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3"
)
```

This doesn't work and results in an error.

I checked the `file:/tmp/hadoop-ubuntu/n...` location and it gets created only when I start a new spark session. How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try `Provided`:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api"       % "1.7.7" % Provided,
  "org.slf4j" % "jcl-over-slf4j"  % "1.7.7" % Provided
)
```

This should exclude them.

And maybe you have to clear the cache `/tmp/hadoop-ubuntu/nm-local-dir/usercache/ubuntu/filecache/`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I cant try this before Monday. Upvoting it though.